# Problema al asignar el valor a un input radio con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, radio, input

Estoy asignando les el valor a mis `input radio` a través de una función que consulta los datos de la base con `jQuery` y `ajax`, está función se ejecuta cada ves que se da clic en un botón.

El verdadero problema es que la primera ves que le doy clic al botón y llama la función todo se ejecuta bien y me muestra los datos pero cuando actualizo los datos y quiero volver a consultarlos ya no me cargan los `input radio` asignando el valor de la base. Cabe recalcar que estos no son los únicos datos que traigo y solo falla con los `input radio`.

Alguien podría decirme ¿por que pasa esto o que estoy haciendo mal?

Esta es la parte de mi código que asigna los valores solo a mis inputs radios

```js
function consultarRegistro(idu){

 const data = {"idguid" : idu};

$.ajax({type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "consultarIu", 
    success: (result) => {
        if(result.periodo_v != "") {
            $(`input[name="periodo_v"][value="${result.periodo_v}"]`).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $("input[name='periodo_v']").prop('checked', false);
        }

        if(result.periodo_a != "") {
            console.log(`introducir el código aquí`result.periodo_a)
            $(`input[name="periodo_a"][value="${result.periodo_a}"]`).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("input[name='periodo_a']").prop("checked", false);
        }

        if(result.periodo_r != "") {
            console.log(result.periodo_r)
            $(`input[name="periodo_r"][value="${result.periodo_r}"`).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $("input[name='periodo_r']").prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Así es como llamo la función

```js
<button type="button" onClick="consultarRegistro('${sucursal.idu}');" class="btn-change-custom-pagina">
```

Este botón esta en una tabla que muestra los datos y a un costado de la tabla están los botones de editar o eliminar el de editar es el que tiene la función que acabo de mostrar

Comment: Falta código. ¿Cuál es la acción que llama a la petición Ajax? Pon el contexto completo. Y, debes aprender a depurar... ¿has hecho alguna prueba, de qué tipo, dónde? ¿Llegan los datos, no llegan, llegan a medias? ¿Por qué no llegan o por qué llega eso y no lo otro? En fin, depuración básica. Puedes usar `console.log` para testear los datos y acotar el problema. Es que, aún poniendo el contexto completo, hay que meterse luego en la lógica que estás siguiendo para determinar el error. Saber depurar te facilitará las cosas y te ahorrará horas  rompiéndote el coco.

Comment: como dije en la pregunta llamo la función desde un botón asi onClick="consultarRegistro('${sucursal.idu_sucursal}');" y si ya lo depure lo revise use console.log y he verificado que todos los datos si que lleguan el problema supongo yo es el código de jQuery que funciona la primera vez y la segunda ya no

Comment: Por favor pulsa en [edit] y pon en la pregunta las explicaciones, no en comentarios. Ni siquiera se entiende qué significa la *primera vez*. Ten en cuenta que nadie es tú, por lo tanto no entendemos lo que estás haciendo, tienes que explicarlo de la mejor forma posible para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Como ya dije, en el código que has compartido no se ve de qué modo se llama a Ajax. Tampoco se entiende qué es *primera vez, segunda vez, tercera vez* ¿? ¿Es un cambio de opciones, es cuando entras de nuevo a la página, es cuando cambias de hora?

Comment: En la pregunta puse que la primera ves que doy clic al botón y llamo la función ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Pero ¿depuraste si la segunda vez entra en la parte de Ajax? ¿depuraste que `idu` está llegando a la función? ¿Depuraste si devuelve algo en el `success` mediante un `console.log(result);`? ¿Qué devuelve? Si aprendes a depurar encontrarás el error.

Comment: Si lo hice y si entra al ajax también como dije en la pregunta los input radio no son los únicos datos que estoy consultando, y al revisar con console.log(result) ahí están todos los datos, lo único que no me coloca son los valores seleccionados de los inputs radios los demás si

Comment: ¿Te refieres por ejemplo a esto: `$(input[name="periodo_v"][value="${result.periodo_v}"]).prop('checked', true);`? ¿Podrías explicar lo que intentas hacer ahí. ¿Podrías agregar el HTML con los `input` en cuestión? Si son del tipo `radio` por ejemplo, **no puedes poner `checked` a varios `input` con el mismo  `name`** que es lo que parece que intentas hacer. Eso no es posible por la naturaleza misma de los input de tipo radio que sólo admiten uno seleccionado, no varios. ¿La consola de Javascript da algún error? ¿qué error?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema lo que hacia luego de guardar los datos era limpiar el formulario dando les un valor igual a "" y en otra función de mi código tenia esto

```js
$("input:checked").val("");
```

Tengan cuidado con este tipo de cosas ya que aquí le estoy diciendo que todos los inputs chequeados tengan un valor igual a nada cuando solo debi dejar

```js
$("input[name='periodo_v']").prop('checked', false);
$("input[name='periodo_a']").prop("checked", false);
$("input[name='periodo_r']").prop('checked', false);
```